# Is it possible to limit or customize owners' permissions in Gilab?

Tags: gitlab

We have a self-managed Gitlab instance of Community Edition. For security reasons, we want to limit some permissions like adding/removing project members. But it seems once a user becomes Owner, he/she has all the permissions that an Owner should have.

Is it possible to disable some of the permissions? Does the Enterprise Edition have this feature?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html

Comment: Thanks, @JoaoVitorino. But I couldn't find the answer in the documentation. It seems Gitlab permissions are just four kinds of roles with respective fixed permissions. What I'm seeking is a way to configure dynamic permissions.